# Change name of vector on data frames of a list

Tags: r, list, names

I have a list with 9 data frames like this

```
Year  Total Counts   Total Overshoot
2015    80               50
2016    100              60
2017    120              70
```

I want to change the name of `Total Counts` to `TotalCounts` and of `Total Overshoot` to `TotalOvershoot` (Delete the space)in all data frames of the list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rename` after looping through the `list` with `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
               rename(TotalCounts = "Total Counts"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also (if the name you want to change is always in the second place):

```
lapply(my_list, function(x){
  colnames(x)[2] <- gsub(" ","", colnames(x)[2])
  x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with base R and `setNames`:

```
lapply(mylist,
       function(x) setNames(x, replace(names(x), names(x) == "Total Counts", "TotalCounts")))
```